# Issues with function to compare user input to method Python

Tags: python

I wrote the function `input_gather` to collect a user's response and compare it to various options, then to run methods based on the response.

```
def input_gather(option_1, option_2, option_3, method_1, method_2, method_3, choice):
    if choice.lower().strip() == option_1:
        method_1()
        return
    elif choice.lower().strip() == option_2:
        method_2()
        return
    elif choice.lower().strip() == option_3:
        method_3()
        return
    else:
        print("Error. Can you repeat that? ")
    return
```

Whenever I call the input_gather function, it will end up running all the other various methods. This is for a text-based adventure game. The full implementation can be seen here:

```
print(intro_to_story)
answer = ""
while (answer.lower().strip() != "y" or answer.lower().strip() != "n"):
    answer = input("y or n >>> \t")
    input_gather("y", "n", None, agree_caesar_is_bad(), disagree_caesar_is_bad(), None, answer)
return
```

When the program quits, it will run all the other methods passed into the function.

Comment: That should probably be `and` instead of `or`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the functions in your main function and passing the results, rather than passing the callables. Remove the calling parentheses:

```
input_gather("y", "n", None, agree_caesar_is_bad, disagree_caesar_is_bad, None, answer)
```